# How to use createAsyncComponent in VueRouter@4.0.0 (Vue3)?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3, vue-router4

When I fill the `component` field in `createRouter()` like this:

```
{
    path: '/article/post',
    name: 'article-post',
    component: defineAsyncComponent({
      loader: () => import('@/views/article-post/index.vue'),
      loadingComponent: () => import('@/views/article-post/skeleton.vue'),
    }),
},
```

Seems like it's not working.
What I want it to show a loading page when the actual page is loading.

How do I do that?

Comment: Possibly worth noting: in my case, it seems like doing a regular lazy loaded `import` route makes the homepage/root route render briefly while the correct route is loading. As such, doing this method, with `defineAsyncComponent`, let's me control what is shown as a loading fallback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`loadingComponent`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/global-api.html#defineasynccomponent) value must be a component definition, and cannot itself be an async component:

```js
import { createRouter } from 'vue-router'
import { defineAsyncComponent } from 'vue'
import Skeleton from '@/views/article-post/skeleton.vue'

export default createRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/article/post',
      name: 'article-post',
      component: defineAsyncComponent({
        loader: () => import('@/views/article-post/index.vue'),
        //loadingComponent: () => import('@/views/article-post/skeleton.vue'), ❌ cannot be dynamic import
        loadingComponent: Skeleton ✅
      }),
    },
  ]
})
```

Also note that the loading component (`Skeleton`) is only shown once, i.e., if the component definition is not already in cache. This [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/using-async-components-in-vue-router-4-p0458?file=/src/router.js) adds an artifical delay in `loader()` to demonstrate.

Comment: This answer is correct. But how about the warning in console, when I use `defineAsyncComponent()` in vue-router?
`vue-router.esm-bundler.js:71 [Vue Router warn]: Component "default" in record with path "/memos" is defined using "defineAsyncComponent()". Write "() => import('./MyPage.vue')" instead of "defineAsyncComponent(() => import('./MyPage.vue'))".`

Comment: Right answer should not include `defineAsyncComponent`. 
Because Vue documentation [states](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/async-components.html#_3-x-syntax) that "You should not use `defineAsyncComponent` when configuring route components with Vue Router".

Comment: Indeed, the route component should be a dynamic import of a wrapper component that contains the `defineAsyncComponent` for the target, as seen in this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-router-async-component?file=src/views/article-post/index.vue).

Answer (score 2):

You can load components asynchronously like this:

```js
{
    path: '/article/post',
    name: 'article-post',
    component: () => ({
        component: import('@/views/article-post/index.vue')
        loading: import('@/views/article-post/skeleton.vue')
    })
},
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use defineAsyncComponent in vue-router and don't get warnings, you can use a wrapper like this:

```
import {defineAsyncComponent, h} from 'vue'
import Loading from 'shared/components/loading.vue'

function lazyLoad(component_name, params = {}) {
  return {
    render() {
      const async_component = defineAsyncComponent({
        loader: () => import(`pages/${component_name}`),
        loadingComponent: Loading,
        ...params
      })
      return h(async_component)
    }
  }
}
```

and then inject it to your route:

```
{
  path: '/',
  name: 'welcome',
  component: lazyLoad('Welcome')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to add to [@Six Stringers answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76640754/2180570) but this was too long to fit in a comment.

That solution won't work if you have nested folders in like `/pages/explore/Search.vue` and want to pass `lazyLoad("explore/Search")`. It's something to do with how Vite ([more specifically Rollup I think](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/dynamic-import-vars#how-it-works)) handles these imports. [Learn more about this, and potential fixes, in this issue](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/4945). The cleanest one, I think, is this (with TypeScript):

```js
const asyncRoute = (path: string) => {
  const component = defineAsyncComponent({
    loader: () =>
      import.meta
        .glob<false, string, Component>("../pages/**/*.vue")
        [`../pages/${path}.vue`](),
    loadingComponent: SomePlaceholderComponent,
  });
  return defineComponent({
    render() {
      return h(component);
    },
  });
};
```

**Also notice one important difference**. `defineAsyncComponent` is only called `once`.

In the original answer, it is called on every `render()`, so it's a new async component definition on every render. Not only is that probably bad for performance, it had a very unusual consequence for me...

I had a table of contents on a page, with hash links to different sections down the page, e.g. `#faqs`. When clicking on one of the hash links, the entire page would appear to reload/re-render (starting at `<router-view />`) and scroll to the top. I eventually tracked it down to this. I think what's happening is... it's expected that a re-render would happen, but since it's a completely new component definition, the re-render starts completely from scratch instead of updating only what changed (and preserving scroll position).

Answer (score -2):

[Note](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html)

Do not use Async components for routes. Async components can still be used inside route components but route component themselves are just dynamic imports.

Comment: Please explain what additional insight this contributes to the existing answers; apart from the link which is not considered part of an answer on StackOverflow.

Comment: The official answer ：Do not use Async components for routes

 component: defineAsyncComponent({
      loader: () => import('@/views/article-post/index.vue'),
      loadingComponent: () => import('@/views/article-post/skeleton.vue'),
    }),

so，defineAsyncComponent is wrong usage in VueRoute

Comment: Apart from the lously formatting enforced by your choice to try and give the code in a comment, it still seems that you contribute nothing beyond what the existing answers have. Please make more obvious what additional insight your answer provides.